# What does the range in a VBA filter function refers to

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Would like to check under ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=", what does the range $O$1583" refer to?

```
 sub Filter  
       ‘Remove empty cell in column G,K,L’
            Range("A2").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select
            Range("B2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="="
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="="
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="="
            Rows("10:10").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583")` is the range, which is going to be filtered. The `A1` is the top left cell and the `O1583` is the bottom right. This cell is in column `O`, row 1583.

The `$` signs could be removed, in VBA they are not important. In Excel `$` signs means that the row or column which comes after the dollar sign is anchored or absolute. When you copy Excel formulas, they will copy cells referred in that formula relative to the position where they are being copied to.

Try this lines to see the range selected:

```
Sub TestMe
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1583").Select
End Sub
```

---

The range is important, because it shows the filtered range. Imagine this data:

[image]

Once you run this `Range("A1:G10").AutoFilter`, you would see that only the values from 1 to 6 are in the filter and `MORE` is not present there. However, if you write values in all the cells from the end of the filter to `MORE` (rows 11,12,13,14) it would be present, as Excel would think that the values have been increased.

Also column-wise you can't filter to a field beyond your range. `Range("$A$2:$B$1583").AutoFilter Field:=3` wouldn't work as you'd be looking to filter by column 3 out of a 2 column range.

Comment: At first I also thought this way. I tried change the ActiveSheet.Range to A1:O1 and I still get back same result. Am I able to conclude the range is redundant ?

Comment: @cheesengng - no. See the updated answer to get the idea. In your case probably there are no empty rows. Make 2 empty rows on row 100 and 101 to see the difference.

Comment: Am I right to say that so long there is no empty space/rows in between, the filter range will auto increase accordingly?

Comment: @cheesengng - yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! have a great day ahead.

Comment: Also column-wise you can't filter to a field beyond your range.  `Range("$A$2:$B$1583").AutoFilter Field:=3` wouldn't work as you'd be looking to filter by column 3 out of a 2 column range.